How to rename a systemd service without restarting the service or the server?
I'm trying to rename a service without restarting the service or the server but I get a Loaded: not-found in the status :
$ systemctl --user status myAPP-instanceName.service | egrep "Loaded:|Active.*running"
     Loaded: loaded (/home/myHOME/.config/systemd/user/myAPP-instanceName.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-07-19 03:03:38 CEST; 3 days ago
$ cd ~/.config/systemd/user
$ mv myAPP-instanceName.service myAPP-newInstanceName.service
$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
$ systemctl --user status myAPP-newInstanceName.service | egrep "Loaded:|Active.*running"
     Loaded: not-found (Reason: Unit myAPP-instanceName.service not found.)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-07-19 03:03:38 CEST; 3 days ago
$ 

How do I do that ?
